# On statistical convergence of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, statistics, asymptotics

A sequence $(x_k)$ is statistically convergent to $L$ if

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}|\{k\leq n:|x_k-L|\geq \epsilon\}|=0.$ 
**(1)**

Also let replace $n$ with $\log n$ as follows:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log n}|\{k\leq \log n:|x_k-L|\geq \epsilon\}|=0.$ **(2)**

(Here, | | represent the cardinality of the set enclosed.)

**My Question:** I am not sure if the following is true:

(1) is satisfied if and only if (2) is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. Use the following facts:

For any $N$ there exists a unique $n$ such that $\log n < N\leq log (n+1)$; as $N \to \infty$, we have $n \to \infty$ and $\frac {\log {(n+1)}} {\log n} \to 1$. $\{k \leq \log n: |x_k-L| \geq \epsilon\} \subset \{k \leq N: |x_k-L| \geq \epsilon\} \subset \{k \leq \log (n+1): |x_k-L| \geq \epsilon\} $.